# Quartile Ambiguity in R

Tags: r, quartile

I have this code in R:

```
data <- c(55, 64, 68, 74, 78, 80, 84, 90, 93, 95)
summary(data)
```

I was expecting the `Median` to be `79`, `1st Quartile` to be `68` and `3rd Quartile` to be `90` according to my previous knowledge.

What I got as an output was `79` for the median, but the `1st quartile` came out to be `69.5` and `3rd quartile` came out to be `88.5`.

I cannot figure out how this output has been generated. Can anyone out there help me with this?

Comment: What does the help file for quantile tell you about this?

Comment: the help file for `median` points to the `quantile` function.  The `quantile` help file discusses the `type` argument,  and R uses type 7 as a default.  It's a different algorithm than what you expect, is all. You could read more about the seven types by reading the Wikipedia entry for "Quantile"

Comment: There are different ways to calculate quantiles.  Your method doesn't match the built in default.

Comment: @Dason I want to know about that built-in default method actually, I mean how does that summary function calculates quartile?

Comment: Thanks all I got the answer, it was indeed the type 7 thing, I figured out how type 7 works for calculating quartiles.